# Weird behaviour of React component that writes to cookies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I have a simple component, that writes to cookies. Minimal working example:

```
function App() {

  // stores cookie
  function setCookie(name: string, value: string, days: number) {
     ...
  }
  // reads cookie
  function getCookie(name: string) {
    ...
  }

  const cookieName = 'testCookie';

  const cookieValue = getCookie(cookieName);
  console.log('cookie value ', cookieValue);

  if (!cookieValue) {
    console.log('going to set cookie');
    setCookie(cookieName, 'test', 1);
    return <h2>Cookie was stored</h2>;
  }

  return <h2>Cookie already exists</h2>
}

export default App;
```

So I want to set cookie on the first run and let the user know that it was stored with `Cookie was stored` output. On the second run the `Cookie already exists` would be displayed.

However I immediately see `Cookie already exists` EVEN when the code executes and logs `going to set cookie`. The `Cookie was stored` is never displayed.

I thought there is a re-render happening, but it is not definitely full re-render as the `cookie value` is logged only once.

Please if you do know why is this behaving in this manner, let me know.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by storing this in a state variable:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
function App() {

    // stores cookie
  function setCookie(name: string, value: string, days: number) {
     ...
  }
  // reads cookie
  function getCookie(name: string) {
    ...
  }

  const [cookieState, setCookieState] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const cookieName = 'testCookie';

    const cookieValue = getCookie(cookieName);
    console.log('cookie value ', cookieValue);

    if (!cookieValue) {
      console.log('going to set cookie');
      setCookieState(cookieName, 'test', 1);
    }
   }, [])

  return cookie ? <h2>Cookie already exists</h2> : <h2> Cookie doesn't exist </h2>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you for finding time to help me.
Your solution has one small drawback - it re-renders the component once cookie has been stored. That's not the use-case I am trying to get.
My use case is like:
1. user sees `Cookie was stored` screen (and cookie is stored)
2. after refreshing the page I read the cookie and then show the other message

Basically I need to persist the state for until page is reloaded.

Comment: The `setCookie` state setter and the `setCookie` custom function have the same identifier, so it's ambiguous which is used in this example, though it looks like the custom function based on the number of arguments.

Comment: I have solved it by introducing `useState` and `useEffect`. Without these the re-render happens, but in a very unpredictable manner.